# Difference between Jenkins Job and Project

Tags: jenkins

When I am on the main Jenkins screen, I get a link to `Create a New Job`.
When I create a new job and call it 'New Job' and run it I get results. When I review the results, I get a link to `Back to Project`.  When I click this I see `Project New Job` on the top of the page.

So is a job and a project the same thing in Jenkins? Or are the names used interchangeably?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, they mean totally the same thing! Below is from the [Jenkins guide](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Building+a+software+project#Buildingasoftwareproject-Settinguptheproject):

> Setting up the project
>
> Go to Jenkins top page, select "New Job", then choose "Build a
> free-style software project". This job type consists of the following
> elements:

It seems the project is the job. Actually when you "create a new job", you will see four types of jobs, and three of them are described as "project".

Comment: That's not entirely correct, although I agree that Jenkins is not consistent with naming. Have a look at the conversation here:http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Is-it-called-quot-Project-quot-or-is-it-called-quot-Job-quot-td4628610.html

Answer (score 12):

This puzzled me quite a bit, too, and although this is an old question I thought I'd expand @Jan's comment with some content from the discussion he linked, as it might help other users.

From the [Jenkins CI forum](http://jenkins-ci.361315.n4.nabble.com/Is-it-called-quot-Project-quot-or-is-it-called-quot-Job-quot-td4628610.html):

> A project is a special case of a job, i.e. all projects are jobs, but
> not all jobs are projects.
>
> Perhaps it helps to extend mentally the names to "*general purpose*
> jobs" and "*software building* projects" (although the latter don't need
> to build software, they are tailored to this use case).
>
> In the case of "new job", Jenkins can't know yet if the new job
> will be of the project subtype. On the other hand, once you have chosen
> to create a project, this is reflected as specific as possible in the UI
> ("Project Foo"). If you look at the precise wording on the "New Job"
> page, you'll realize the subtle differences (e.g. "Build a free-style
> software *project*" as opposed to "Monitor an external *job*").
>
> An example of a job that is not a project is the lesser known
> "external job" that receives notifications from events that happen
> outside Jenkins, but should be tracked inside Jenkins (e.g. system
> restarts, etc.). See
> https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Monitoring+external+jobs for
> more about this job type.
>
> For the records, this is the actual class model used by Jenkins internally
> (extending sub-classes are indented below their super-class):
>
> ```
> Job 
>    AbstractProject 
>       MatrixProject            (a.k.a. "multi-configuration project") 
>       Project 
>          FreeStyleProject 
>          MatrixConfiguration   (a single configuration of a matrix project) 
>    StubJob 
>    ViewJob 
>       ExternalJob
> ```
>
> Only FreeStyleProject, MatrixProject, and ExternalJob are visible on the
> "New Job" page.

Answer (score 5):

*Job* is a [**deprecated**](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/glossary/#job) term that is synonymous with *Project*. They both mean:

> A user-configured description of work which Jenkins should perform, such as building a piece of software, etc.