# Difference between Job and Item

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, project, jobs, items

They seem to be the same, but I am thinking that the people that added a second term should have some reason for that, so I might be wrong.

It would be great if someone could clear out the fog surrounding this terminology!

---

<sub>I was going to create my first Hello world project in Jenkins (which should be the [same as a job](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902242/difference-between-jenkins-job-and-project)), but I am not sure which "New" I should go for, since this [tutorial](https://github.com/jbankes/Hello_Jenkins) says "New Item", but if a project is a job, then I wouldn't want a new job instead?</sub>


<sub>I tried both options, and both lead to the same wizard, where you choose the type of the project (for example freestyle project).</sub>

Comment: Probably this may clear your doubts https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17902242/difference-between-jenkins-job-and-project

Comment: @zaidwarsi this exactly the link I have in my question. It answers the project vs job, while I am asking about job vs item.